# How to change my statement to print frequencies of object member type in hashmap?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I created an arrayList of student objects with various attributes. Among those attributes are favorite color. So in this arraylist of n students, each student has a string favoriteColor member variable.

```
Set<student> studentUnique = new HashSet<student>(studentList);
for (user key : studentUnique) {
    System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(studentList, key));
}
```

I would like to count the frequency of said colors so for example with a hundred students, maybe output:

```
red: 50
blue: 20
green: 30
```

I put my arrayList of students (studentList) into a hashmap but I don't know how to write my frequency statement to get the frequency of students that like their respective colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you're doing is called "grouping" based on the favourite color.

Here is another approach:

```
 Map<String, Integer> result = 
         studentList.stream()
                    .collect(toMap(Student::getFavouriteColor, s -> 1, Math::addExact));
```

This uses the `toMap` collector, where the `keyMapper` is `Student::getFavouriteColor` i.e a function extracting the students favourite color as the map key.

Second, we place the `valueMapper` function `s -> 1` i.e. a function taking a `Student` and return `1` as the map value.

Lastly, we provide a "merge" function `Math::addExact` which is a function used to add two corresponding values given a key clash based on the favourite colour.

So, as a result, we will have a map from `String` ---> `Integer` where each entry in the map represents the color and the number of times that color has been chosen as a "favourite color" amongst the students' list.

Further, if you want to print this result in an ascending order based on occurrences, you can sort the result and print as follows:

```
studentList.stream()
           .collect(toMap(Student::getFavouriteColor, s -> 1, Math::addExact))
           .entrySet()
           .stream()
           .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
           .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue()));
```

imports needed:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

Comment: .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println(entry + ":" + e.getValue())); 
How is entry being printed? does that refer to the individual student object? or an attribute?

Comment: @mobcityzkore it was a typo, I've edited it now. `e.getKey()` refers to the "thing" we've grouped by i.e. the student favourite colour and the `e.getValue()` refers to the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 5):

```
studentUnique.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                  Student::getColor, 
                  Collectors.counting()))
```

Assuming `getColor` exists.

Comment: is there a way to make this ascending? as in blue = 20, green = 30, red = 50?

Comment: @mobcityzkore ascending by color?

Comment: ascending by frequency (basically count)

Comment: @mobcityzkore not really in a `Map` what if you have `20 = blue`, `20 = red` - how will you want this to a `Map` where keys can not be duplicates? may be `20 = [red, blue]`?

Comment: I used aomine's forEachOrdered function tidbit, appreciate your help